# Using ajax .load(), my script is not loaded. but show when page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the jQuery `.load()` to load my fresh data but this removed my other function. When i refresh the page, the missing function shows again.

So in short, when i use the function with the `.load()`, it basically removed my other scripts.

```js
$(".new_container").load(".new_container > *");
```

Comment: The jQuery `load` method *replaces* the HTML content of your element, therefore any items, scripts, etc, inside of that element, will be removed. From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/): *"`.load()` sets the HTML contents of the matched elements to the returned data."*

Comment: The first argument to [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) should be a URL, not a selector

Comment: what's weird is, my other scripts are still showing, the one missing is under a loop